# Making a hyperlink in Seaside with an image as the clickable item

Tags: html, smalltalk, seaside

I am building a website using Instantiation VisualAge Smalltalk Seaside.  I know about the following.

```
renderContentOn: html
  html anchor
    url: 'http://www.seaside.st';
    with: 'Visit the Seaside'.
```

However, I want to make a link where an image is the clickable item and some descriptive text below. What I am doing at the moment is building this in html and having Seaside render the code. I would like to use Seaside to build the item in the same way as above but cannot find any hints. The code I use is like this:

```
html html: '<a
href="http://www.mywebsite.com:8080/Show some details?', imagePath, '"><img
style="border: 0px solid ;  
  text-align: right;height: 130px;" alt=""
src=" http://www.mywebsite.com:8080/images/',  imagePath, '"></a>
<br> some text'
```

Is there a better (and more Smalltalk) way?

---

'Show some details' is my sloppy typing. It is, of course, a valid class name.

However, I have tried this but following 'html text: 'Some text'.' which should just display the text , it also presents the current page class - So, if my class was DPAClassName so
url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com:8080/Show some details?, imagePath'; becomes

url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com:8080/DPAClassName?, imagePath';

the display shows the text 'Some Text but as follows:
'Some Text'DPAClassName

Answer (score 7):

The key is in the `with:` message send to any *tag* (`anchor`, `image`, `paragraph`, etc.), you can pass any *renderable* object to it.
In your first example you passed a `String`, but you can also pass a `BlockClosure` or any other object that understands `renderOn:`.

So, summarizing, the equivalent to what you want would be:

```
    html anchor
      url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com:8080/Show some details?, imagePath';
      with: [
         html image
           style: 'border: 0; height: 130px;'
           url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com:8080/images/',  imagePath ].
    html break.
    html text: 'Some text'.
```

---

As a side note, I think the `Show some details` part of the URI is questionable, as well as passing the imagePath without naming the parameter. But that is certainly something outside of the scope of your question.